# Getting Invalid normalized color error when changing image color in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, canvas

I want to change the background color of my canvas from the script. The following script is attached to the canvas:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CanvasController : MonoBehaviour {

    Color lightBlue = new Color(173, 222, 246);
    Color purple = new Color(107, 62, 143, 255);

    void Start () {
        Image img = transform.GetComponent<Image>();
        img.color = lightBlue;
    }

    void Update () {

    }
}
```

However, when I press play the color turns white and I get two errors:

> Invalid normalized color: RGBA(107.000, 62.000, 143.000, 1.000), normalize value: 0
> UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()
>
> Setting normalized color with a non-normalized color: RGBA(107.000,62.000,143.000,1.000)
> UnityEditor.DockArea:OnGUI()

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Color` you have to pass a value between 0 and 1.

You can use `Color32` to pass values between 0 and 255.

Links to documentation for [Color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html) and [Color32](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color32.html)

Comment: @bonishadelnorte If my answer solved your problem consider accepting it by clicking the check mark.